# php pass id into modal

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm stuck again! So hopefully you awesome people can help me...

So far what I have is a search function that queries the database, and returns results, which works fine, and then the user can click one of the results, which takes them through to a new detailed page of what they clicked, for example a brand. Then on the detailed page, it returns all of that brands details (using $_GET['id']) and a new set of data, from a relational table, with a list of all the offers corresponding to that brand, which also works. But then I get stuck, I want the user to be able to click on each offer, and have the details of that offer load into a modal... I've tried using the $_GET['id'] for the offers id, but obviously, with it being on the same page (i presume), it passes the id of the brand / parent instead of the offer.

This is the code that calls back all the offers relating to the brand

```
$offers_sql = 'SELECT * FROM codes WHERE client_id LIKE :client_id AND CURDATE() between start AND expiry';
$offersq = $db->prepare($offers_sql);
$offers_params = array(':client_id' => $id);
$offersq->execute($offers_params);

$results = $offersq->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if(count($results) < 1) {
        $output = "<h4>no current offers available</h4>";
    }
    else {
        foreach($results as $r) {
        $title = $r['title'];
        $code = $r['textcode'];
        $offer_id = $r['id'];
        $expiry = $r['expiry'];
        $date = new DateTime($expiry);

        $output .= '<h4><a href="#?id=' . $offer_id . '" class="md-trigger" data-modal="offer">' . $title . '</a></h4><hr>';

    }
}

} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "failed to load offers";
}
?>
```

and this is the code i was using for the modal

```
require('inc/connect/config.php');
include('inc/result.php');
$page_title = "Title - " . $name . " Offers";
include('inc/style.php');
include('inc/header.php');
include('inc/offers.php');

?>

<!-- Intro Section -->
<section class="intro-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h3 class="navbar-fixed-top">Latest Deals</h3>
                <h1><?php echo $name; ?></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="offer-section">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
            <?php echo $output; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>

<div class="md-modal md-effect-flip" id="offer">
<div class="md-content">
<h4><?php $offer = (int) $_GET['id'];
echo $offer ?></h4>
<button type="submit" class="modal-btn md-close navbar-fixed-bottom" value="submit"><p>close</p></button>
</div>
</div>

<?php include('inc/footer.php'); ?>
```

The code that returns the details of the brand is on a separate page, but i can include that if necessary.

What am i doing wrong? Please go easy on me, I am relatively new to php.

Thanks in advance

Kaylee

Comment: I work with modal in different way. If you are OK. Then i can post my code here.

Comment: thats fine with me, what you got?

Comment: wait. making your answer only. more 3-4 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Make Changes, Where Output is declared in else condition. (Changes Done)

$output='<h4><a class="OfferIdClass" data-OfferID="<?echo $offer_id;?>" href="#offer" data-modal="offer" data-toggle="modal">'.$title.'</a></h4>';

// Add This to footer.php (Changes Done)

<div class="md-modal md-effect-flip" id="offer">
    <div class="md-content">
    </div>
</div>

//Add this below in that page, where you are clicking Modal.

//Changes Done 
<script>
    $('.OfferIdClass').click(function(){
    var OfferID=$(this).attr('data-OfferID');
    $.ajax({url:"Open-Offer.php?OfferID="+OfferID,cache:false,success:function(result){
        $(".md-content").html(result); //Here, Changes Done
    }});
    });
</script>
```

//Create one Open-Offer.php page. (Changes Done)

**Open-Offer.php**

```
<?
extract($_GET);

<h4><?php $offer = (int) $_GET['id'];
echo $offer ?></h4>
<button type="submit" class="modal-btn md-close navbar-fixed-bottom" value="submit"><p>close</p></button>
?>
```

Comment: Hi, Yes it worked, it changed the styling of the modal etc, but thats something I can fix, Thanks!

Comment: it changed because modal which is used is default modal of bootstrap.. which you can change easily. Thats why i mentioned bootstrap.css.. If It Is working fine.. please reward me for my work while ticking this as right answer. It will mean a lot @KayleeSmith ..

Comment: Hi Danish Enam, I'm struggling a little with changing the code to use the styling in my css and not bootstrap. I have managed to change it so that the modal content is styled how I need it to be, but I cant seem to get it to open / close with my styling without it bewing glitchy, or just not working. I think the issue lies with the "modal" and "fade" class for the modal div, and also the "modal-dialog". I have my own styling that flips the modal, rather than fade in / out, and more specifically positions it in the center of the screen when open, and is a particular size. any ideas?

Comment: Wait @KayleeSmith. Just Coming In 10 Minutes. Will Try To Help.

Comment: ok thanks. Its also interfering with another modal I have on the page, with a different id etc, and that is using my styling, but if i click on that modal after clicking an offer modal, it loads the offer modal rather that the one it is supposed to

Comment: Hi @KayleeSmith. I'm Editing my answer. But, before. I Request You to copy my existing code in some other file. (for backup purpose only.)
 After copying my existing code, notify me. I will edit my answer. Thanku.

Comment: And, one more thing.. why another modal interfering is because.. i think you used same class name in <a href=""></a> change class name here like class="OfferIdClass1" & class="OfferIdClass2".
Same in ajax code also, $('.OfferIdClass1').click(function(){ & $('.OfferIdClass2').click(function(){.. Use This.. If After Changing your code.. Another modal interfers.. let me know..

Comment: I have a copy of your code. I haven't used the same class in <a href=""> </a>... so that cant be the reason why it is interfering with my other modal.

Comment: Changes Done. Check It.  Without Getting Tensed. Try In A Cool Manner. I Hope It Will Work. Because, I Changed My Modal With Yours Modal. Let Me Know @KayleeSmith?

Comment: no that didnt work... it loads an overlay, but no modal